# Xfce, Thunar: How to get file path in title bar?

Tags: xfce

I understand that this feature is not yet available (https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5920) but is there a workaround for getting Thunar to display a file's path in the title bar (like in the Terminal Emulator for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The workaround is compiling Thunar yourself with [this patch](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/attachment.cgi?id=2639) from the bug report. Since the patch is old, it may not apply automatically (with `patch`)...sorry.